# How do I code for a series of promises where the data inputted into each promise depends on the outcome of the previous promise?

Tags: javascript, foreach, stripe-payments, es6-promise

Please read the query before directing me to previous answer about Promise.all or async await.

I  am trying to charge a number of cards using the Stripe API and Promises.

If the charge is successful, refunds will issue to other customers.

The amount of the charge depends on the price of the tickets that will be refunded.

Some of the charges will fail (customer doesn't have enough money on credit card etc) so I need to wait to find out if the charge (promise) is successful or not before moving onto the next charge (promise).

I was hoping to ensure the correct refunds are used to calculate charges by using splice in the .then() if the charge was successful and not using if the charge wasn't successful.

Finally, I was planning to call other functions when all charges have been completed using the code:

```
i===waitListToCharge.length-1
```

as a condition.

The code is running but the promises seem to be firing ahead before the previous ones are finished and the condition is triggering before all promises have finished - posting errors to my database. I don't understand why.

I originally tried using a promise within a while loop but that didn't work either. Outline of code is here

What's the best way to approach this problem?

```
  let refundsCopy = ticketsToRefund.map(e => e) 

   waitListToCharge.forEach((e,i) => {

    **code to calculate correct price and charges

        let ChargeCard = stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        ***code to execute charge on stripe api
    })

    Promise.allSettled([ChargeCard])
    .then(data => {

    //if successful
    if(data[0].status === 'fulfilled'){
    successfulPayments.push(data[0])
    refundsCopy.splice(0,e.quantity)

    }else {
    console.log('payment failed')
    failedPayments.push(data[0])
    }



    if(i===waitListToCharge.length-1){

    callOtherFunctions(successfulPayments, failedPayments, eventData, ticketsToRefund)
    }

    })

    })
```

I tried using async await on the suggestions of others but the same problem occurs. The code I used was:

```
    async function testPromise(){
  **code to calculate correct price and charges
  let ChargeCard = stripe.paymentIntents.create({

}
)
  let data = await Promise.allSettled([ChargeCard])


    if(data[0].status === 'fulfilled'){
     successfulPayments.push(data[0])
     refundsCopy.splice(0,e.quantity)

 }else {
    failedPayments.push(data[0])
 }


 if(i===waitListToCharge.length-1){
    callOtherFunctions(successfulPayments, failedPayments, eventData, ticketsToRefund)
 }

}

testPromise()


})
```

UPDATE: I have this working by basically coding my own forEach loop. The code is below. Was there a simpler way?

```
    const myOwnForEachFunction = (e, i) => {

**code to calculate correct price and charges
let ChargeCard = stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  ***code for stripe
})

Promise.allSettled([ChargeCard])
.then(data => {

if(data[0].status === 'fulfilled'){
    console.log('payment success')
 successfulPayments.push(data[0])
 refundsCopy.splice(0,e.quantity)

}else {
console.log('payment failed')
failedPayments.push(data[0])
}



if(i===waitListToCharge.length-1){
callOtherFunctions(successfulPayments, failedPayments, eventData, ticketsToRefund)
}else{
myOwnForEachFunction(waitListToCharge[i+1], i+1)
}

})


}

myOwnForEachFunction(waitListToCharge[0], 0)
```

Comment: To start with, you might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths. You might also consider using `//` for comments (which is valid syntax, unlike `**`)

Comment: Your first snippet will result in a `ReferenceError` because `ChargeCard` is not in the outer scope when you call `Promise.allSettled`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Would the code have worked if I defined ChargeCard before the forEach? Why? Promise.allSettled was working correctly - it just wasn't waiting for the code in the .then() to execute before moving onto the next iteration

Comment: `forEach` is synchronous - at best it can start asynchronous operations but it doesn't wait them to finish - and its return value is discarded. In the updated code `Promise.allSettled([ChargeCard])  ... if ... else...` is an antipattern (overly complicated code) for `ChargeCard.then ... catch...`

Comment: Using forEach with Promises is very tricky because as @traktor53 said it doesn't wait for them to finish even if you use async/await. I suggest to use a `for of` instead it's pretty much the same as forEach but if you use async/await it waits for the Promises to be complete in every iteration.

Comment: Your code will still not loop through the way you want it to here.  You need to use something like async / await or Promise.all or caolan/async in order to do this, and you need to use that code for the loop, not inside a (synchronous) loop.

I'm also a bit curious as to your use case here.